# Removing streams with active clients

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I want to remove a task stream of a user who has left the company. So I go

```
p4 stream -d -f //depot/stream
```

The system answers :

```
Stream '//depot/stream' has active clients; cannot delete until they are removed.
```

Very well, I will remove the active client as well. So I am looking for it with :

```
p4 clients -S //depot/stream
```

Which then gives nothing.

So either I missed some options, either there is some kind of bug that is hiding some client. This is not a right issue because I have already removed plenty of streams or clients.

Alternatively is there another way to force the removal ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some trials, I used

```
p4 clients -a -S //depot/stream
```

And suddenly there was a match. `-a` search clients on all servers.

I was logged on an edge server, and apparently the user had created some of its workspace on the main server. I logged in on main and removed the annoying workspace from there.

Answer (score 2):

See if you have a workspace tied to the stream.  I recently had the same issue and when I deleted the associated workspace, I was able to delete the stream.